# malloc() weirdness - always 8 bytes allocated?

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm experiencing some behavior I don't understand with malloc.

For instance, allocating memory for a structure works just fine, i.e.:

```
typedef struct my_struct {
        char buffer[4096];
        struct my_struct *next;
} MY_STRUCT;

...

MY_STRUCT *ptr = (MY_STRUCT *)malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct));
        printf("malloc() gave us %lu bytes\n", sizeof(*ptr));
        printf("My structure's first member is %lu in length\n", sizeof(ptr->buffer));
        free(ptr);

...
```

Returns

```
malloc() gave us 4104 bytes
My structure's first member is 4096 in length
```

...exactly as expected.  Now, when I try to dynamically allocate a buffer for a character string:

```
int bufsize = 4096;
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*bufsize);
printf("bufsize: %d\n", bufsize);
printf("Allocated buffer size: %lu\n", sizeof(*buffer));
free(buffer);
```

...returns

```
bufsize: 4096
Allocated buffer size: 8
```

Now, I can hard-code the `malloc()` call to 4096, 1, 4, anything really... It always comes up 8.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: You can't use the pointer returned by `malloc` to find the memory allocated. The memory allocated, if successful, is what was asked for, that is, you already know it.

Comment: [Obligatory warning about casting the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Hmm -- there's something else weird in op's post. `sizeof(*buffer)` for `char* buffer` should give 1, not 8.

Comment: The correct format for printing a `size_t` value (such as the result of `sizeof`) is `"%zu"`. `sizeof(*buffer)` *should* yield `1`, not `8`. The declaration of `buffer` is more simply written as `char *buffer = malloc(bufsize);`. `malloc()` returns `NULL` if it fails; always check for that. If it doesn't return `NULL`, it allocated the size you asked it to.

Comment: ^^ It's odd how often the most complete answer (Keith's) is in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof` tells you what the compiler thinks the size of something is.

If `ptr` is a `MY_STRUCT*`, then `sizeof(*ptr)` will always be the same as `sizeof(MY_STRUCT)`. That's true *even* if ptr points to NULL, or to an array of `MY_STRUCT`s, or to memory that's already been freed, or so on.

`sizeof` cannot be used to tell you the size of a memory block allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: Thank you!  I will accept as soon as it lets me.  Makes perfect sense now that you've explained it.